# How does file encryption in work in Travis CI?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, https, travis-ci

I cannot completely understand how Travis encrypts files. Let's say I want to run `https` server on Node.js, so I need a private key file and cert file. I don't want to keep my private key in repo, so I encrypt it via Travis. I have two questions:

1. Will it work if I use encrypted file instead of original one in options of https server?
2. If answer on the first question is true, what stops other people from taking my encrypted file and using it?

Comment: Did you try 1.?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not yet, I am just planning to get ssl certificate and try it.